# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.blog_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have this error showing in my laravel project. I made `blogs` and `categories` columns in my database. My migrations:
Categories:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Blogs:

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->string('description', 900);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

And these are relationships between models:
My `Blog` model:

```
public function category(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category');
}
```

And my `Category` model:

```
public function blogs(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Blog', 'category_id');
}
```

And when I create a new blog post it shows me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.blog_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`blog_id` = 16 and `categories`.`blog_id` is not null limit 1)
```

but my blog post is stored correctly in database with `category_id`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your relations are incorrect, because one category can have many blogs

Category Model:

```
public function blogs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Blog');
}
```

and blog belongs to one category

Blog Model:

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `blog_id` column to your `categories` table.
For a `hasOne` relationship, it is the `belongsTo` model that carries the id of the table it belongs to. Your code should be as follows:

**Categories**

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('blog_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('blog_id')->references('id')->on('blogs');
});
```

**Blogs**

```php
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->string('description', 900);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Blog Model**

```php
public function category(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category');
}
```

**Category Model**

```php
public function blogs(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Blog');
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing relationships between models. Thank you anyway Sir!